# Error starting MongoDB on CentOS

Tags: mongodb, centos

When I run the `mongod --dbpath /data/db` command to start MongoDB, I get the following error message:

```
oot@vps [/]# mongod --dbpath /data/db
2015-11-17T21:10:54.048+0000 SEVERE: terminate() called, printing stack (if implemented for platform):
0x121d451 0x121c6d8 0x7f77f06c7bd6 0x7f77f06c7c03 0x7f77f06c7d22 0x771858 0x1262158 0x121ceb9 0x76fc75 0x76ff69 0x7f77efdfbd5d 0x766529
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x121d451]
 mongod() [0x121c6d8]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbcbd6) [0x7f77f06c7bd6]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbcc03) [0x7f77f06c7c03]
 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbcd22) [0x7f77f06c7d22]
 mongod(_ZN5boost15throw_exceptionINS_21thread_resource_errorEEEvRKT_+0x1c8) [0x771858]
 mongod(_ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv+0x138) [0x1262158]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadEv+0x299) [0x121ceb9]
 mongod() [0x76fc75]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x76ff69]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f77efdfbd5d]
 mongod() [0x766529]
```

I am new to MondoDB and Linux servers, so really not sure where to start with this, there doesn't seem to be any usefull info in the error.

Has anyone else had anything similar? Or any ideas on where to start with fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this turned out to be caused by not enough memory

I concluded this after running some of the commands found in this article: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-memory-usage/

`egrep --color 'Mem|Cache|Swap' /proc/meminfo` will output how much memory is available. Don't forget that Mongo itself will require memory, so even if you have got a bit of free mem, it may not be enough.

I restarted my server, which killed a few of the memory sucking processes, and this for now has solved my problem.

Comment: A little more info would help. How much memory did you have? How did you conclude that it was a memory issue? Did you change some setting to make it work?